# How to "undo" what mousedown did by clicking on another element?

Tags: javascript, raphael

This is what the mouse down does:

```
one_element.mousedown(function(){
    this.attr({stroke:"#ffffff"});

    el2.attr({stroke:'#ffffff'});
    el3.attr({stroke:'#ffffff'});  
});
```

and i want to undo it when another element is clicked. Basicly the stroke will go back to black, on click it is white. 
I would be grateful for your help, I know it is a basic question, but it has been bugging me for hours

Comment: This looks like JavaScript, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this:

```
two_element.mousedown(function(){
    this.attr({stroke:"#000000"});

    el2.attr({stroke:'#000000'});
    el3.attr({stroke:'#000000'});  
});
```

Assuming your other element is called two_element

---

**Edit**

You can put this code in a function and toggle it on/off depending on what element was selected.  Your main function would look something like this:

```
function myFunction(isOn)
{
  if(isOn){ 
     el1.attr({stroke:'#ffffff'});
     el2.attr({stroke:'#ffffff'});
     el3.attr({stroke:'#ffffff'}); 
  }else{
     el1.attr({stroke:'#000000'});
     el2.attr({stroke:'#000000'});
     el3.attr({stroke:'#000000'}); 
  }
}
```

Element one can turn this on by:

```
one_element.mousedown(myFunction(true));
```

Element two turns off this by:

```
two_element.mousedown(myFunction(false));
```

Comment: There are ten element that cause changes to at least four other elements on mousedown. I wanted to know if I can just "undo" the change with a single line of code once another element is clicked. I can do it like this, but I thought there is a better way

Comment: What about putting it in a separate function and then just toggling On/Off based on the current state?  You might want to add more info to your question above to get a answer that better meets your needs.

Comment: Yes! That is what I wanted anwsered. Thank you. Can you show me how?

Comment: I updated the answer. Note that this is untested but should get you going in the right direction.